# Clarification on bounties

Tags: support, bounty

I'm trying to understand the bounty mechanics better. I know the bounty rep is immediately subtracted to the OP rep, irrespective of whether the question gets an answer or not.

Suppose the question gets multiple answers, but the OP doesn't select any. Once the bounty period expires, what happens? Does the question with more votes get the bounty?

Now consider a different scenario: the bounty period expires before the question gets any answers. Now, if someone writes an answer, she/he won't get the reward, irrespective of whether the OP selects the answer or not. Right?

Comment: exactly, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Possibly http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/what-happens-to-the-bounty-if-theres-no-answer?rq=1 might help you.